# Bench-marking my SSD gives unreasonable number

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance, sata, benchmarking

I have a **SAMSUNG 840 EVO SSD (120GB)** installed on my laptop. According to the SAMSUNG website, it has 520 MB/s max read and 500 MB/s max write (sequential).

I am trying to benchmark it using **CrystalDiskMark3.03b** as following:

[image]

As you can see, the sequential Read/Write speeds doesn't make sense at all. I think even with the fastest SSD drives, it would be almost impossible to achieve 3GB/s read and write as the SATA 6Gb/s interface will limit the speed.

I have checked the specification of benchmarking software and 1MB is indeed 1000,000 bytes.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try another benchmark. I'd trust only a benchmark I've written myself. And even that might lie since you don't know what hardware voodoo happens. I guess you see just cache usage in your benchmark.

Comment: have you tried to disable the Rapid mode? Are the values now near to what you see in other benchmarks in the Internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see those high values, because you use the [Rapid Mode.](https://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/downloads/document/Samsung_SSD_Rapid_Mode_Whitepaper_EN.pdf) Run Samsung's SSD Magician and disable it:

[image]